# Clone parent div of selected event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I right click on link, I want to fetch all the code of its parent div and it should be cloned after this div.

I have tried some code but it is not working, please see my code below. I would also like to remove the selected parent `div`.

Below is my code:

```js
// when we're about to show the context menu, show our own instead
$(document).on("contextmenu", function(event) {
  // Avoid the real one if this is the link
  if ($(event.target).hasClass("sim-row-edit")) {
   console.log("right click identified");
  
  // add border
  $(event.target).parent().addClass("selected");
  
    event.preventDefault();
 clicked_link = $(event.target).text();
 clicked_url = $(event.target).attr("href");
 clicked_id = $(event.target).attr("id");
 
 //$(event.target).text("ttt");
 
 //alert(clicked_link);
    // Show contextmenu
    $(".custom-menu").show(100).
    css({
      top: event.pageY + "px",
      left: event.pageX + "px"
    });
  }
});

// hide our context menu when the document is clicked
$(document).on("mouseup", function() {
  $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
  $(".selected").removeClass("selected");

});

$(".custom-menu li").click(function() {
  //alert("hii2");
  // This is the triggered action name
  switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
    // A case for each action. Should personalize to your actions
    case "first":
     // console.log("first");
    console.log("-----");
    console.log(clicked_link);
    console.log(clicked_url);
    console.log(clicked_id);
    
    
    //trying to clone the div using below code but it is not working.
    thisDiv = $(event.target).parent();
    $(thisDiv).clone().insertAfter(thisDiv);
 
   //console.log($(this).parent().text());
      break;
    case "second":
      console.log("second");
      break;
    case "third":
      console.log("third");
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.custom-menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}

.custom-menu li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #4679BD;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <div>
  Lorem..
  <a href="http://goo.com" id="id-goo" class="sim-row-edit" data-type="link">right click on me and click clone, but its not working</a>
  </div>
   
   
   <div class="sim-row-edit">
   <a href="http://voo.com" id="id-voo"  data-type="link">voo</a>
   </div>
   
<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <li data-action = "first">Clone</li>
  <li data-action = "second">Second thing</li>
  <li data-action = "third">Third thing</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML doesn't have a `<div>` as the parent of the `<ul>`

Comment: I want to clone the div parent of text lorem, right click on the link, context menu will open, click pn clone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example, in the event handler `$(".custom-menu li").click= function() { ... }` `event.target` points to the `li` element and getting its `parent` gives you `ul` element which gets cloned and inserted inside `ul` giving a nested list i.e. a context menu inside context menu.

To resolve, take a reference of the clicked element when right-clicked along with other properties and refer inside this event handler to make a clone. See the code for understanding.

```js
// when we're about to show the context menu, show our own instead
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Document ready');
});

$(document).on("contextmenu", function(event) {
  // Avoid the real one if this is the link
  if ($(event.target).hasClass("sim-row-edit")) {
    console.log("right click identified");

    // add border
    $(event.target).parent().addClass("selected");

    event.preventDefault();
    target_element = $(event.target);
    clicked_link = $(event.target).text();
    clicked_url = $(event.target).attr("href");
    clicked_id = $(event.target).attr("id");

    //$(event.target).text("ttt");

    //alert(clicked_link);
    // Show contextmenu
    $(".custom-menu").show(100).
    css({
      top: event.pageY + "px",
      left: event.pageX + "px"
    });
  }
});

// hide our context menu when the document is clicked
$(document).on("mouseup", function() {
  $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
  $(".selected").removeClass("selected");

});

$(".custom-menu li").click(function() {
  //alert("hii2");
  // This is the triggered action name
  switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
    // A case for each action. Should personalize to your actions
    case "first":
      // console.log("first");
      console.log("-----");
      console.log(clicked_link);
      console.log(clicked_url);
      console.log(clicked_id);
      console.log(target_element);


      //trying to clone the div using below code but it is not working.
      console.log(event.target);
      thisDiv = target_element.parent();
      thisDiv.clone().insertAfter(thisDiv);

      //console.log($(this).parent().text());
      break;
    case "second":
      console.log("second");
      break;
    case "third":
      console.log("third");
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.custom-menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}

.custom-menu li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #4679BD;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    Lorem..
    <a href="http://goo.com" id="id-goo" class="sim-row-edit" data-type="link">right click on me and click clone, but its not working</a>
  </div>


  <div>
    <a href="http://voo.com" id="id-voo" data-type="link">voo</a>
  </div>

  <ul class='custom-menu'>
    <li data-action="first">Clone</li>
    <li data-action="second">Second thing</li>
    <li data-action="third">Third thing</li>
  </ul>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this was working fine on the above testing html but on my real html page it is giving me value of `thisDiv` as `jQuery.fn.init [div.img-top.context_image, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]`